# Prove that there is a unique seminorm $p$ on $V$ s.t $\{x \in V : p(x) < \alpha \} \subset U \subset \{x \in V : p(x) \leq \alpha \}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ and let $U \subset V$ be a convex, balanced and absorbing set.

Prove that there is a unique seminorm $p$ on $V$ s.t $\{x \in V : p(x) < \alpha \} \subset U \subset \{x \in V : p(x) \leq  \alpha \}$.

I need a hint

**EDIT**

Using the Minkowski functional.
Define 
$$
p(x) = \inf \{ \alpha > 0 : x \in \alpha U \}
$$

Let $v \in \{x \in V : p(x) < \alpha\}$. Now we have that $\frac{p(x)}{\alpha}$ < 1. Thus using that $U$ is balenced then $\frac{p(x)}{\alpha} U \subset U$.
What can I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$p(x)=\inf\{t:\ x\in tU\}.$$

Because $U $ is absorbing, $p $ is well-defined. Because it is convex and balanced, it is a seminorm.

If $x\in U$, then $x\in 1\cdot U$, and so $p_U(x)\leq1.$ That is, $$U\subset\{x\in V:\ p(x)\leq1\}.$$

If $p(x)<1$, this means that there exists $t\in[0,1)$ such that $x\in tU$. But $U$ is balanced, so $tU\subset U$ and so $x\in U$. Then
$$
\{x\in V:\ p(x)<1\}\subset U.
$$

The uniqueness occurs for a fixed $\alpha$. Since everything is scalable, we may assume $\alpha=1$. So assume that $q$ is a seminorm and that $$\{x\in V:\ q(x)<1\}\subset U\subset\{x\in V:\ q(x)\leq1\}.$$
If $x\in U$, then $\beta=q(x)<1$. Then, for any $\varepsilon>0$, $\frac1{\beta+\varepsilon}\,x\in U$, since $q(\frac1{\beta+\varepsilon}\,x)<1$. But then $p(\frac1{\beta+\varepsilon}\,x)<1$, so $$p(x)<\beta+\varepsilon=q(x)+\varepsilon.$$
As we can do this for any $\varepsilon>0$, we conclude that $p(x)\leq q(x)$. As the roles of $p$ and $q$ are reversible, we obtain that $p(x)=q(x)$ for any $x\in U$.

Finally, if $x\not\in U$, there exists $\gamma>0$ such that $\gamma x\in U$. Then
$$
\gamma p(x)=p(\gamma x)=q(\gamma x)=\gamma q(x),
$$
so $p(x)=q(x)$.

Comment: In the beginning you write "if $x \in U$, then $ x \in 1 \cdot U$". Here it seems to me that you have assumed that $\alpha = 1$. Why can we do that? Is it because of the "Since Everything is scalable, we may assume $\alpha = 1$?

Comment: Yes. The $\alpha$ is not unique. If you have $$\{x\in V:\ q(x)<1\}\subset U\subset\{x\in V:\ q(x)\leq1\},$$ you also have $$\{x\in V:\ r(x)<2\}\subset U\subset\{x\in V:\ r(x)\leq2\}$$ for the seminorm $r(x)=2q(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint on where to start: [Minkowski Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional) (and, of course, your inclusions are reversed).

Comment: I used your hint, but I got stuck pretty fast.